# SPI. When does the RXNE bit of the SPI_SR register become 0?

Tags: stm32, spi

I found information that the `RXNE` bit is set to `0` when the `SPI_DR` register is read.
So after this code the `RXNE` bit will be cleared?

```
uint8_t result;
result=SPI1->DR;
```

It's hard for me to imagine that the `SPI_DR` register keeps track of when SPI_DR will be read.
By reading I mean this:

```
result=SPI1->DR;
```

**I thought that the `RXNE` bit became `0` when the value from the `RX` buffer was transferred to the `SPI_DR` register.**
Whether I read `SPI_DR` or not, that’s my business.
Isn't that right?

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t Read_Out_X_Y_Z_REG_Address=0xA8;
    uint8_t Out_X_Y_Z_Data_Separate[6]={0};
    int16_t Out_X_Y_Z_Data_RESULT[3]={0};

    
SPI1->CR1  |= SPI_CR1_SPE; 
uint8_t address=0x8F; //Register address+read
uint8_t result;
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //Chip Select
while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
SPI1->DR = address;
while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
while((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY) != RESET);
    
while((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));
result=SPI1->DR;  //STARTING HERE I COMMENT THE CODE FOR THE EXPERIMENT.
while((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE)); 
while((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY) != RESET);
    
while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
SPI1->DR = 0;
while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
while((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY) != RESET);

while((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));
result=SPI1->DR;
//while((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));
while((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY) != RESET);

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET); //Chip Select
}
```

Comment: "I thought that the RXNE bit became 0 when the value from the RX buffer was transferred to the SPI_DR register." -> No, the RXNE bit becomes **1** when data is transferred to the DR register. RXNE means **R**eceive register **N**ot **E**mpty. Not Empty means "ready for you to read by accessing the DR in your code"

Comment: As written, I would expect your code to hang at the 1st `while((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));` line above your "STARTING HERE" comment. In the code above that, then you sent a byte, the SPI peripheral received a byte at the same time. So as soon as the BSY flag gets RESET, it will transfer that received byte over into the DR and set RXNE to 1, so you while loop will just hang there forever.

Comment: It seems to me that you have confused the RX buffer with the Data Register.
<RXNE: Receive buffer not empty
0: Rx buffer empty
1: Rx buffer not empty>

Comment: <No, the RXNE bit becomes 1 when data is transferred to the DR register. >
No, the RXNE bit is set to 1 when the RX buffer is full.
This is what it says in the Reference Manual.
<1: Rx buffer not empty>
RXNE CANNOT HAVE A VALUE OF 1 IN BOTH EVENTS AT THE SAME TIME.
That is, when transferring data from the RX buffer to DR.
And if the RX buffer is full.
You described it in such a way that in these two events RXNE has a value of 1, this cannot be so.

Comment: Ok thanks.
I thought that RX buffer and SPI_DR are different things.
I didn’t understand why if the RX buffer is full, then we need to read SPI_DR.
It turns out that SPI_DR and RX buffer are almost the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is about STM32 MCU family, and there are many small and large MCUs in the family, each with either with either very simple or very complex SPI peripheral.

What is common to all of them is that RXNE bit signals if there is data to read or not. And reading the data through the data register does update the RXNE bit.

If you don't read the data, RXNE stays high.

Same thing for UART received data so it is not that surprising.

Some STM32 models have a complex SPI with a FIFO so you can simply tell it to transfer e.g. 8 bytes and you can keep reading a byte every time RXNE is set until you have read 8 bytes and FIFO is empty.

For further details, read the Reference Manual for your specific MCU.

Comment: I did an experiment.
SPI_SR_RXNE is cleared without reading SPI1->DR.
Maybe I'm wrong, but in my opinion clearing SPI_SR_RXNE signals the transfer of data to the SPI1->DR register, and not reading SPI1->DR.

I'm using code that sends data to SPI1->DR.
From this code I will write only one line.

<//result=SPI1->DR; //DEACTIVATED.>
If I don't read data from the DR register, then SPI_SR_RXNE is still cleared.

Comment: @stm writing to the SPI1->DR register in your code has no effect on SPI_SR_RXNE. RXNE gets set by the hardware when data is transferred by the hardware from the RX shift register into the DR, ready for you to read in your code. It gets cleared by the hardware when your code reads that data out of the DR. Writing data to the DR by your code is a TX operation, not an RX operation, and as such has no effect on **RX**NE.

Comment: @stm Which exact STM32 model you have, e.g. STM32F100RB, STM32H743VI, etc? All five characters after STM32 are important.

Comment: @Justme, STM32F407VGT6

Comment: @brhans, 
 <This is a Receive operation: result=SPI1->DR;>
<This is Transmit SPI1->DR=result;>
In the example above, I described the Receive operation. Data arrives in the RX buffer, I wrote this. I just wrote only one line of code.

Comment: @stm The reference manual for F407VG is clear on this - RXNE gets cleared by reading the Data Register and it gets set after Shift Register is copied to RX buffer so it is available from reading throuh Data Register. You don't show the code of your experiment so it might be incorrect or do other things that clear the RXNE flag.

Comment: @Justme, Maybe under "reading the DR register" there is meaning something else. For example, transferring data to the DR register? My code is for the accelerometer, I don't clear the SPI_SR_RXNE bit myself. After the deactivated line <//result=SPI1->DR; //DEACTIVATED.> There is no more code at all. Do the same experiment for yourself, send something to the RX buffer, DO NOT READ DR REGISTER and look at the state of the SPI_SR_RXNE bit.

Comment: @stm No it literally means the software accessing the DR register address with a read operation. Show your full code and it can be tested. Also if you are single stepping through the code with a debugger that also can fetch register status to you, it can affect the status seen by your code. Has happened to me and SPI did not work when debugging it

Comment: @Justme,
My experiment proves the opposite, RXNE is cleared when data is transferred to the SPI1->DR register, and not when the SPI1->DR register is read.
I pasted the full code into the first message.
This is the code for the accelerometer, when sending data to the accelerometer, in response the accelerometer sends data to the Microcontroller.

Comment: @stm If that is your code, does it work? I mean, there is no code to enable GPIO or SPI peripheral clocks, so if you get wonky readings, no wonder. Do you ever see RXNE high, to prove what sets it low again?

Comment: @ Justme,
The code works. I'm getting data from the accelerometer.
I wrote code related only to the accelerometer.
Of course, the code contains the necessary code to enable and configure the necessary pins.
But this is not important for this topic, the main thing is that the code is working and everything is configured correctly.
Yes, I saw the SPI_SR_RXNE bit being activated and deactivated.

Comment: Ok thanks.
I thought that RX buffer and SPI_DR are different things.
I didn’t understand why if the RX buffer is full, then we need to read SPI_DR.
It turns out that SPI_DR and RX buffer are almost the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that the RXNE bit became 0 when the value from the RX buffer
> was transferred to the SPI_DR register.

No, your conclusion is completely wrong.

> Whether I read SPI_DR or not, that’s my business. Isn't that right?

Not right, you need to read the register to clear the RNE. Some SPI peripherals have FIFOs and imagine that you have not one, but four received data chunks. DR register is only one.

> I'm using code that sends data to SPI1->DR. From this code I will
> write only one line.

When you write to the DR register you access another register. The peripheral detects the direction and diverts the data to the appropriate place. So you have two registers exposed at the same address.

When you write something to this register and SPI sends data, you ***always*** receive data too. So the `RXNE` bit will be set even by the write to DR register. But ***it is not the data*** you wrote to it.